# Uninstalled XCode still paused in 'Purchases,' will not resume or delete

Tags: xcode, macos

I was trying to re-install XCode, but have run into trouble. I first uninstalled it by deleting the `.app` file from the Finder, and then rebooted my machine. Upon returning to the App Store, I saw that XCode was listed as 'Paused' under purchases, with 0 GB downloaded, and will not resume or download again.

When I click `Resume`, nothing happens. There is no icon in the launcher, and running `xcode-select -p` outputs:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

But there is no 'XCode' in this folder.

I basically just want to uninstall everything to do with XCode, and re-install it. I'm running Yosemite 10.10, if that helps.

Edit: I also tried deleting the `com.apple.appstore` folder, to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clearing **com.apple.appstore** from the TMPDIR.

```
open $TMPDIR../C
```

and

```
open $TMPDIR../T
```

find **com.apple.appstore** and delete it from both the folder.  Then restart the App Store.

Comment: That did it, thank you! (Or at least, made it disappear from the queue, will try and install again now-- cheers!)